# How can I write a simple Python try block that only check if a function returned as true?

Tags: python

Pretty new to Python, trying to use a try/except block that tests if the output of a function was true or not. The function takes a simple input from the user and validates it. I want to do something like this:

```
try:
    if(test_function()):
    print('Input from test_function was true.')
except:
    print('Input from test_function was false.')
```

But as you can probably see, it never hits the except portion of the code.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This is what an `if` statement is for. `try`-`except` is for catching *exceptions*.

Comment: you need to raise an error to get in the except part

Answer (score 2):

This is not a try/except situation; this is a simple **if** statement:

```
if(test_function()):
    print('Input from test_function was true.')
else:
    print('Input from test_function was false.')
```

Try/except is for code that may raise an exception, such as

```
try:
    if(test_function()):
        print('Input from test_function was true.')
except:
    print('test_function tried to do something illegal ... :-)')
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed, it looks like you don't need a `try`, `except` block, just a simple `if`, `else`. But I have seen some circumstances where you want to raise the exception on a condition and the pattern would be:

```
try:
    if not test_function():
        raise ValueError  # Or some other sensible exception
    print('Return from test_function was true.')
except ValueError:
    print('test_function tried to do something illegal ... :-)')
```

But generally you would use `try`, `except` if the `test_function()` raises the exception:

```
 def test_function():
     if bad_condition:
         raise ValueError
     return True

 try:
     print('Return from test_function was {}.'.format(test_function())
 except ValueError:
     print('test_function tried to do something illegal ... :-)')
```